# Extracting Files from Sharepoint 2013 WSS_Content Database

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Sharepoint 2013 stores documents in the WSS_Content database in a table called DocStreams.

Up until Sharepoint 2010, files where stored in a single row in a VarBinary column. Since Sharepoint 2013, files are stored in multiple rows using Shredded Blob storage.

Does anyone know how I can piece together the files from the shredded storage in c#?

I have found many exampled online to extract files from SharePoint 2010 and earlier but they only support a files content being stored in 1 row.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this? The whole point of a document management system is that users should be able to access documents without trying to fiddle with the database. Especially an undocumented database. Documents are directly accessible by their URL. Libraries are available as network shares. There *is* a client library that can be used from Javascript.

Comment: PS even in 2010 documents were *not* stored in a single row - they could be stored externally by installing an external storage provider. SQL Server's FILESTREAM feature could be used for this

Comment: I would be interested in an answer also, the most I've been able to find out from research is that file shredding is handled by Micosoft.Cobalt (sometimes called CobaltCore) within Sharepoint. As for _"Why"_ we would want to do this... Sharepoint's indexing has proven to be slow and easily corruptible, so we wanted to rip everything out of Sharepoint into a different blob/document storage system. But after spending a large amount of time being unable to merge shredded or versioned documents back into a true file, we had to get Sharepoint back online to let it serve the documents up to migrate